# Is it safe to vacuum or blow with manual pump a PC if the nozzle is grounded ?

Tags: cleaning, static-discharge

From what I read, static charge can be built up by the dust going against the plastic of the pump/vacuum, hence the risk of doing so.

But if I simply connect the plastic nozzle of the pump/vacuum to the ground (with, I don't know, copper wire to the power plug ground for instance) the discharge won't go on the components, right ? So that should be safe if carefully done or I miss something ?

Comment: Valid assumption. Here is my own experience. I have used a not grounded vacuum cleaner plenty of times to clean the PC and never had a problem.

Comment: Plastic isn't particularly electrically conductive, so it's not clear to me how you intend to electrically "connect" a plastic nozzle to ground. This question might be easier to answer if you elaborate on how you plan to do that. You could also do something like use a can of compressed air (carefully) to blow dust in the direction of the vacuum cleaner nozzle.

Comment: Well, from my understanding, it doesn't matter how I would "connect" the plastic nozzle. if a spark can pass through air from it to a conductor, it'll more likely go to the shortest/more conductive route, that is, not the air gap. (so, I may just touch the end of nozzle with anything conductive that is linked to the ground really). Again, do I miss something obvious ?